# UI is laggy when using serial communication

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, serial-port

Good day!
I want to read data from serial port. The data can be read every 2 secs and save it to a database, and luckily did it. I used a datagridview to display and save it. But it seems very laggy. I must wait for a few seconds to be able to click another button.
Are there other ways on how to do this?
Any help would do. Thanks!

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class PICtoVB[enter image description here][1]
Dim connString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=C:\Users\Recto D Sanchez Jr\Desktop\Datalogger GUI\test\test\bin\Debug\database1.accdb"
Dim MyConn As OleDbConnection
Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter
Dim ds As DataSet
Dim tables As DataTableCollection
Dim source1 As New BindingSource
Dim timerval As Integer = 0

Private Sub btnconnect_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnconnect.Click
    btnconnect.Enabled = False
    btnread.Enabled = True
    btndisconnect.Enabled = True
    SerialPort1.Open()
    Timer1.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub btndisconnect_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btndisconnect.Click
    btndisconnect.Enabled = False
    btnread.Enabled = False
    btnconnect.Enabled = True
    Timer1.Enabled = False
    SerialPort1.Close()
End Sub


Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    timerval = timerval + 1

    Dim serialdata1 As String
    Dim serialdata2 As String
    Dim serialdata3 As String
    Dim serialdata4 As String

    Try
        serialdata1 = SerialPort1.ReadLine.ToString
        serialdata2 = SerialPort1.ReadLine.ToString
        serialdata3 = SerialPort1.ReadLine.ToString
        serialdata4 = SerialPort1.ReadLine.ToString
        dgvdata.Rows.Add(serialdata1, serialdata2, serialdata3, serialdata4)
        DATALOGBindingSource1.AddNew()
        DATETextBox.Text = serialdata1
        TIMETextBox.Text = serialdata2
        TEMP__C_TextBox.Text = serialdata3
        RH____TextBox.Text = serialdata4
        DATALOGBindingSource1.EndEdit()
        DATALOGTableAdapter1.Update(Database1DataSet1.DATALOG)

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're reading data from the `SerialPort` on the UI thread, which means that it is too busy to maintain the UI, hence the UI freezing for periods.  Generally speaking, you handle the `DataReceived` event of the `SerialPort` and read data there.  That event handler is executed on a secondary thread, which means that you can read and manipulate data as much as you want without affecting the UI.  You can't update the UI from there though, so once you have processed the data and are ready to display it, you need to marshal a method call to the UI thread and do the updating there.  That's a topic you can find lots of examples for.

Comment: Do you mean I need to create another form to read the data? I'm still a newbie for vb.net. Please bear with me.

Comment: If I meant that you should create another form then I'd have said that you should create another form.  What I said was that you should handle the `DataReceived` event of your `SerialPort`.  I said that mainly because you should handle the `DataReceived` event of your `SerialPort`.  What exactly about being a beginner prevents you from typing "serialport datareceived event" into Google?

Comment: @Werdna, as I said in my answer, the `DataReceived` event is raised on a secondary thread.  If your comment relates to the question itself and not specifically to my answer then it should be posted against the question and not against my answer.